Equivalence between revised simplex and tableau simplex
I am working through the equivalence of each step of the two algorithms.
Wagner's 1957 "A COMPARISON OF THE ORIGINAL AND REVISED
SIMPLEX METHODS" states that they are rigorously the same (not equivalent: the same).
However, the revised simplex applies to $Ax = b$, while the tableau simplex uses $Ax \leq b$ and introduces slack variables $z \geq 0$ such that $Ax + z = b$.
I understand that this is equivalent, but:
The tableau simplex is most often presented in the case $b \geq 0$: while (multiplying some constraints by -1) this is easy to enforce in the $Ax = b$ case, I don't see how one can enforce this in the $Ax \leq b$ case.
This is crucial since it allows to initialize the tableau simplex with $x = 0, z=b$ and have a convenient initial basis. On the contrary, the revised simplex has no such assumption.
Am I missing something?

The Simplex Tableau can be mapped like so:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BV&z&Variables&RHS\\\hline
z&1&C_{BV}^TB^{-1}N-C_{NBV}^T&C_{BV}^TB^{-1}b\\\hline
\begin{array}{c}x_1\\\vdots\\x_m\end{array}&\begin{array}{c}0\\\vdots\\0\end{array}& \begin{array}{c}B^{-1}A\\or\\B^{-1}A_j\end{array} & B^{-1}b\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
Which contains the same elements as the Revised Simplex method. The Simplex Tableau relies on the same standard formulation as the Revised Simplex Method. In other words, it cannot operate for $Ax\le b$ formulation. For the general standard form linear program
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
max & z= c^Tx\\
s.t.& Ax=b\\
    & x\ge0
\end{array}
$$
It maps to the Simplex Tableau like so:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
BV&z&x_1&x_2&x_3&\ldots&x_n&s_1&s_2&\ldots&s_m&RHS\\\hline
z&1&-c_1&-c_2&-c_3&\ldots&-c_n&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\\hline
s_1&0&a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&\ldots&a_{1n}&1&0&\ldots&0&b_1\\\hline
s_2&0&a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&\ldots&a_{2n}&0&1&\ldots&0&b_2\\\hline
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\\hline
s_m&0&a_{m1}&a_{m2}&a_{m3}&\ldots&a_{mn}&0&0&\ldots&1&b_m\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
where $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_m$ are the slack variables from the $Ax\le b$ conversion. Additionally, the Revised Simplex and the Simplex Tableau methods require $b\ge0$ for basic feasible solutions. If we have a negative $b$ from the start for a constraint, and we multiply the constraint by $-1$, resulting in $\ge$. Then, we introduce a negative slack variable and start with the route of artificial variables. The Revised Simplex method operates under the same considerations as well.
The only difference between the Simplex Tableau and the Revised Simplex method is that the Revised Simplex method doesn't focus on keeping all the excess, unneeded, data for values not being considered in the basis. In other words, the Revised Simplex Method takes advantage of the fact that we don't need to calculate the $A_j$ columns of positive reduced cost non-basic variables, nor do we need to need to calculate the $A_j$ of all the columns of possible entering non-basic variables. Thus, making the method computationally faster than the Simplex Tableau method. But functionally, they are the same.

One could imagine the Simplex Tableau being the "full data" version of the Revised Simplex method where everything is calculated per iteration
